# Delphi XE 5 Windows application compatibility on Windows 10 operating system

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I have developed windows application in Delphi XE 5, I need to know that whether the application works fine on Windows 10 operating system? If not then which version on Delphi I should use

Comment: Yes , target 64 bit excutables

Comment: In general it should work. XE5 does not support Windows 10 per monitor DPI. Other than that how can we know whether your application works fine?

Comment: @Sami 64bit executables are not necessary

Comment: Your applications will run on Windows XP and newer.

Comment: why not? I still have some old Delphi 5 applications that are running fine on Windows 10

Comment: @smooty86 Not necessarily. Depends what the code is.

Comment: Whether or not your program works on a particular OS depends on what's in your program. Only you know that. We cannot help you there.

Comment: I wanted to add a note that it depends a little but officially Windows since XP are supported as per help (though it may work on any older version and at the same time does not have to run on some newer if he uses any not supported API).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can install **XE5** on Windows 10, and the **executables** that it produces **are compatible with Windows 10.**

Embarcadero have been producing a lot of marketing that implies that you need XE8 to do Windows 10 development. Truth be told, you can use any version of Delphi beyond Delphi 1. Of course the newer versions make life easier, and clearly you need XE2 or later to target 64 bit executables.

Comment: You would need at least Delphi 2 which first introduced 32 bit compiler and support for 32 bit application. Delphi 1 was still producing 16 bit applications. And these could no longer be run even on Windows 2000 any more. I believe Windows Millennium was the last one that supported running of 16 bit applications.

Comment: @SilverWarior: "beyond Delphi 1" means Delphi 2 or higher.